# Grafana pod in kube-prometheus-stack app unable to detect configmap for datasources

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, rancher, configmap

I have installed an instance of kube-prometheus-stack (https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) onto a Rancher cluster and utilised a custom values.yaml to add Grafana configuration.

Grafana section of values.yaml:

```
grafana:
  enabled: true
  ingress:
    enabled: disabled
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    annotations: {}
    labels: {}
    portName: service
  sidecar:
    image:
      repository: kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar
      tag: 1.1.0
      sha: ""
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    skipTlsVerify: true
    enableUniqueFilenames: false
    dashboards:
      enabled: true
      SCProvider: true
      label: grafana_dashboard
      folder: /tmp/dashboards
      defaultFolderName: null
      searchNamespace: ALL
      folderAnnotation: null
      provider:
        name: sidecarProvider
        orgid: 1
        folder: ''
        type: file
        disableDelete: false
        allowUiUpdates: true
        foldersFromFilesStructure: false
    datasources:
      enabled: true
      label: grafana_datasource
      searchNamespace: ALL
```

I have also stored a configmap into Rancher prior to installation called `grafana-datasource` and has the label: key: `grafana_datasource` with value: `1`. This configmap is stored in the same namespace as the kube-prometheus-stack app.

In this `grafana-datasource` configmap, I have put the following data:

```
apiVersion: 1
datasources:
- name: Test-Prometheus
  type: prometheus
  url: https://prometheus.test.net/
  access: proxy
  isDefault: false
  basicAuth: true
  basicAuthUser: admin
  basicAuthPassword: password
  withCredentials: false
  isDefault: false
  version: 1
  editable: true
```

I have verified that my datasource exists and am able to log into it and add it manually via the Grafana GUI. However, the installation is not picking up my `grafana-datasource` configmap and only loads the default Grafana datasource:
[image: grafana_default_datasource]

How can I enable my grafana to pick-up and apply the custom datasource configmap on installation?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your setup and everything was working correctly.

It seems that you may have skipped the `.yaml/.yml` extension for the configmap filename (and since you are not mentioning what name you used, this is the most probable cause). Add the one like following and it should work.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  custom.yaml: |
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: Test-Prometheus
      type: prometheus
      url: https://prometheus.test.net/
      access: proxy
      isDefault: false
      basicAuth: true
      basicAuthUser: admin
      basicAuthPassword: password
      withCredentials: false
      isDefault: false
      version: 1
      editable: true
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: grafana-datasource
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using adding a job to restart the grafana server in the grafana pod. Since I use argocd to automate my deployments, this is managed for me

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: grafana-reload-job
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: monitoring-grafana
      containers:
        - name: kubectl-exec
          image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args:
            - -c
            - |
              POD=$(kubectl get pod -n monitoring -l app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
              kubectl exec -it -n monitoring $POD -- sh -c "kill \$(ps aux | grep '[g]rafana server' | awk '{print \$1}')"
      restartPolicy: Never
```